# Discord.py bot clear

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Alright so guys i need some help. Basically i am making an discord bot. I'm having problems with clear(purge) command. So this is my code so far:

```
@client.command(aliases= ['purge','delete'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount : int):
   if amount == None:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000000)
   else:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

my problem here is this  `if amount == None` .
Please help me!
Im getting an error that i have missing requied argument...

Comment: Could you include the whole error message in your question as well as how you call your command in discord ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not giving `amount` the default value `None`. This is how you should define the function:

```
@client.command(aliases= ['purge','delete'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=None): # Set default value as None
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000000)
    else:
        try:
            int(amount)
        except: # Error handler
            await ctx.send('Please enter a valid integer as amount.')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['purge', 'delete'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = 1000000):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
```

This should work, as I have a clear command that looks almost exactly like this. The `amount` param is being converted to an int and if the client doesn't give parameters, the amount will be set at `1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clear(ctx , amount=5):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
```

I got it from a youtuber channel, you can put the number of the messages u want to clear after the clear command, EX:
**-clear 10**

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I'm using atm.

```py
@bot.command(name='clear', help='this command will clear msgs')
async def clear(ctx, amount = 50): # Change amount
  if ctx.message.author.id == (YOUR USER ID HERE):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
  else:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} you are not allowed")
```

I've just added an 'if' statement for being the only one who can use that command. You can also allow an specific role.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    await ctx.message.delete()

client.run("token")
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
@client.command(aliases= ['purge','delete'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount :int = -1):
   if amount == -1:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000000)
   else:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

I think it should work, if the client doesn't give parameters, the amount will be  set at "-1"